# Heatmap processed on the whole layer / dataset

Tags: geoserver, wms, leaflet, sld, heat-map

How can I process the geoserver heatmap on my whole database rather than on the displayed part of it?

What I want is to keep the same color for each place, everytime.
Here is an illustration of what I get currently.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I try to modify the bbox by sending a parameter to my sld "env: 'testBBox:'+17589+','+6132191+','+383205+','+6309986" but it doesn't work. I get the error "Rendering process failed
Could not convert the value 17589,6132191,383205,6309986 into the expected type class org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope for parameter outputBBOX"

Comment: My data are static so maybe there is a way to create a static heatmap layer?

Comment: Does someone know where I can find the WPS heatmap source code? I want to rewrite it for computing my entire dataset.

Comment: Did you ever find the source code? I'm looking for it too: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/253092/2788

Comment: Fyi.. this is still not resolved even in latest versions of Geoserver. Did anybody find a workaround for this?