# Where is the GeoServer heatmap rendering transformation source code?

Tags: geoserver, heat-map, wps

I'm trying to find the source code for the GeoServer Heatmap rendering transformation. I can't find anything relevant in the [GeoServer GitHub repo](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver).

[This page](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implement-rendertrans.html#transformation-process-class) in the developer guide includes a code snippet from the transformation but when I search for `"public class HeatmapProcess implements GeoServerProcess"` that page in the developer guide is the only result.

I'd like to learn how the transformation produces grid cell values as there's no documentation on the internal logic.

Comment: firefly-orange, can you give a example for use heatmap? Please.
Thank you

Comment: @GiancarloBrunoHonores please don't hijack questions. Please ask a separate question and elaborate - A LOT!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoServer uses the heatmap process from GeoTools. [Here](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/vector/HeatmapProcess.java) is the link.